# Newsletter Subscription Popup Script for Prestashop

Tags: popup, prestashop

I like to show newsletter subscription popup window whenever a new customer visit our site. Once he register then until unless he will not clear the cookies he cant find same window again.

I wish to do it for prestashop.

Will be great if anyone assist me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you may already know, PrestaShop modules extend the core functionality adding functionalities to PrestaShop without having to edit its core files. Module creation is explained in the [Creating a PrestaShop module](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module) section in the developer guide.

If you cannot find an already written module that fits your needs (free or paid), you will have to create one yourself. Basically you have to:

- extend the Prestashop's `Module class` where you set the module's attributes,
- hook your module, see [available hooks](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.5) (`displayHeader` hook may be appropiate for you),
- write the hook event handler, that is, the code that will render your content. Prestashop uses Smarty engine, so set the variables for your template here,
- write the template code, which in your case will probably be some Javascript checking the condition (passed as a Smarty variable) that checks whether the popup should be displayed or not, and the popup code (f.e. using jQuery-ui popup) with the needed content, f.e. the email form input, etc.

Comment: Thanks all for suggestion. Will try & let u know.